# Vertically align two Text QML types with different font.pixelSize values

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

```
Text {
     id: firstText
     x: 50
     y: 570
     text: "4.4"
     font.pixelSize: 60
     font.family: sansGuiltMB.name
     color: "#0085CA" 
}

Text {
    id: secondText
    anchors.left: firstText.right
    y: 570
    text: "m/s"
    font.pixelSize: 28
    font.family: universalisRegular.name
    color: "#0085CA3"
}
```

Output:

[image]

I'd like *secondText* to be at the bottom. Why is it stuck at the top? I've tried to use verticalAlignment, verticalCenter, ligneHeight but nothing changed.

**EDIT:** adding `anchors.bottom: firstText.bottom` does work but *firstText* is not vertical aligned with *secondText*:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
anchors.bottom: firstText.bottom
```

works for me.

**Edit:**
Replace

```
anchors.bottom: firstText.bottom
```

to

```
anchors.baseline: firstText.baseline
```

I think it what you want:

[image: Fixed vertical align]

Comment: It partially fixes the problem but _firstText_ is not vertical aligned with _secondText_. I guess this is because of the pixelSize values.